# Session locking in 8.2

Tags: session-state

Occasionally we are experiencing what appears to be a session lock when viewing the front end of the site.

The symptoms are

- The browser loads the request for a long period of time
- Eventually a 504 gateway timeout is returned
- If you make the same request in a different browser or in incognito the site loads straight away

I have had a similar experience in 8.2. when using Xdb and tracking which is described [here](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/sitecore-8-and-tracker-current-session-identify-overriding-expired-contact-session-lock-for-contact-id/) but in this case we have disabled Xdb through `<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="false" />`.

I have noticed that when this occurs there is nothing notable in the logs other than multiple entries of:

`HttpModule is being initialized`

We are using Redis for session storage and Sitecore 8.2 rev 161221 (update 2).